# "What's beta" in Help Center: Do we still need it?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I was looking through the help center recently, and noticed the [What's beta?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) page. Is it even necessary anymore? I understand that we have not completely graduated yet, but we are not in beta any more.

Should it be kept there as of right now? If it stays, when should it be removed?

Comment: *we have not completely graduated yet* - huh? We'll get our community ads at next cycle, what else is missing? ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Community ads :)

Answer (score 10):

[Stack Overflow's Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) also has a "What's Beta?" page.  It's a generic page that is present on all sites, and doesn't mean anything about our status.

I don't think it's that harmful to leave it there, but if you want, you can point this out on [Stack Exchange meta](//meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6):

The page explains things that no longer apply to the site. It explains what beta is and how the process works for sites that are still proving that they have value. Code Review the latter half hasn't really been relevant for CR as it was pre-approved for graduation long ago, and the other half is no longer relevant since nowhere says "beta" any more.

I'd say we can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it be kept there as of right now? If it stays, when should it be removed?

Right now? Keep it. As long as we don't have our community ads we are not running a full fledged graduated site.

There have been arguments about when beta stops. In my opinion beta stops when we have gained every and all benefits from a graduated site. That said, beta pages should be removed when we're confident not a single part of the site could indicate we're still in beta.

We're almost there. But those pages don't hurt anyone if they stick around till we really left the beta phase behind us.

Note: This is all assuming community ads are indeed the only thing we're missing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If this is within what we can change, and not SE-wide, then it should probably go.  Any remnant mentions of Beta on main (rather than Meta) are probably obsolete.

Perhaps we should also retire *"How to Ask Questions in Private Beta"* from [help/asking](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking).